# Code with curly braces in/after "new"?

Tags: java, syntax, curly-braces

```
private static ThreadLocal<Connection> connectionHolder = new ThreadLocal<Connection>() {
    public Connection initialValue() { 
         return DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
    }
};
```

I don't understand what's going on in the part that's within the stars. Is that a way to insert a  method into a class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do curly braces in "new" expression mean? (e.g. "new MyClass() { ... }")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468806/what-do-curly-braces-in-new-expression-mean-e-g-new-myclass)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [initialValue()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html#initialValue%28%29) method of ThreadLocal is just a way to construct a ThreadLocal holding a value other than null.

Edit: Oh, I see that's not what you're asking about. What you have there is the same as if you did:

```
public class MyOwnThreadLocal extends ThreadLocal {
    public Connection initialValue() {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
    }
}
```

Except your version doesn't require a completely separate class definition--hence it's called an "anonymous class".

Comment: so if i'm understanding you correctly then the variable connectionHolder is actually not a ThreadLocal object, but a nameless subclass of the Threadlocal object?

Comment: Exactly correct. If you look at the compiled output, you'll see a class file named "<name of the class containing connectionHolder>$1.class". That's how anonymous classes are compiled.

Answer (score 5):

This is an anonymous inner class - see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html#innerClasses

Answer (score 3):

Within the stars you have an anonymous inner class it means :

- you are embedding a class in a class (so it's an inner class)
- the inner class is defined within a method body (so it's an anonymous inner class)

it's a syntax shortcut to implement a behavior for an interface or abstract class without declaring a full standard Java class. You are defining a precise behavior for a fixed context.

Next, for the ThreadLocal part,based on the [ThreadLocal Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) the connectionHolder field is managed by many theads.

> Each thread holds an implicit reference to its copy of a thread-local variable as long as the thread is alive and the ThreadLocal instance is accessible; after a thread goes away, all of its copies of thread-local instances are subject to garbage collection (unless other references to these copies exist).

If you have 5 threads wich access to the connectionHolder you will found 5 ThreadLocal which managed the 5 instance of the value

Answer (score 2):

This is an [Anonymous Inner Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html#innerClasses) that are usually implementing some interface that is a callback or something similar, Swing uses this for listeners.

In this case it is implementing the `initialValue()` method on that particular instance of `ThreadLocal<Connection>`.

You can override methods on single instances of Objects this way, so if you want just a particular instance to behave in a different way you can override as many methods on that instance you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is an anonymous inner class. It is a short syntax for extending a base class:

```
class AnonClass extends ThreadLocal<Connector> {
    public Connection initialValue() { 
         return DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
    }
}
```

private static AnonClass connectionHolder = new AnonClass();

You could do the same thing with interfaces (most commonly seen when implementing callbacks). For example:

```
interface Callback {
    void doIt();
}
```

Callback test = new Callback() {
   public void doIt() { /* ... */ }
};