# Curly braces in "new" expression? (e.g. "new MyClass() { ... }")

Tags: java, android, class, syntax, curly-braces

What do the curly braces do there ?

```
handler1 = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage() {

       }
};
```

`object = new Class_Name() {};` ?
This syntax exists only on Android or Java also? And what is it called in Java? Thank for your helps.

Comment: Related / duplicate question : ["Difference between new Test() and new Test() { }"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22164036/320399)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is the syntax for creating an instance of [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) that extends `Handler`. This is part of Java.

Comment: Thank you very much. I lost so much time for this:((.

Answer (score 3):

This is happned when you create the instance reference of the Interface.
For example I want to create the instance of the interface `Runnable` with the class, then I can create it by creating an anonymous class for the same and override the `run()` method of the interface. You can understand well by looking at the another example other then you stated below.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Instantiates & returns reference of an anonymous subclass of current class.

```
new Handler() {};
```

Inside curly braces, definition of anonymous subclass (to be named as *Handler$1* by compiler after compilation) can be specified.

> It is as equal as extending the *Handler* class explicitly but it requires name specification obviously of subclass & so it will not remain anonymous any longer.

Following code might help to understand **Instantiates & returns reference of an anonymous subclass of current class.**

```
class Main{
    int a = 5;
    void func(){}
    void meth(){
        Main ref2 = new Main() {
            void func(){
                System.out.println(a);
            }           
        };
        ref2.func();
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main mm = new Main();
        mm.meth();
    }
}
//5
```